# Scrape a cart process with curl, php and simple_html_dom on musicmagpie

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I've written a script that works with our websites cart systems but Music Magpie is proving difficult.  It doesn't seem to hold the session for me to get the result.

I'm guessing they try to stop this from happening but as far as I can see I'm doing this right.  Any suggestions?

My code is:

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

function grab_via_proxy_combination($url,$fields)
{


foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2400);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS,2400);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0 FirePHP/0.6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,2400);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
$cookie_file = "cookies/magpie.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
if ($fields) {curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields)); } 
if ($fields) {curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); }


    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $res = $html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);


    if (strlen($res) > 100) {
    return $res;
    }
    else {


    }

}


$fields = array(
                        'barcode' => urlencode('711719274551')
                );



$html = grab_via_proxy_combination('http://www.musicmagpie.co.uk/Sellit.asp?result=nq&barcode=0711719274551&loc=103',$fields);

echo $html;
```

Comment: My guess is that CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION is the culprit

Comment: How to scrap ajax loaded data?